# Groupby to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a groupby and I want to convert JUST the groupby (no counts, sums, etc) to a Dataframe and then export that to a CSV.

This is essentially just finding all of the unique combinations across a few columns of data.  If it is easier to do without using a groupby, I would be fine with that too.

I tried using reset_index() and got the following message.

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

data = pd.DataFrame([['a','z'],['a','y'],['b','y'],['a','y']],columns=['one','two'])
gb = data.groupby(['one','two'])['one'].count()
```

I just want to output a 3 row DataFrame with the unique combinations of 'one' and 'two'.

Comment: Can we see some examples of the input and output data? Preferably the input should be copy-pastable, so we can just paste into a Python console and start working with it straight away.

Comment: great, these little mock datasets make it much easier to answer pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the unique combinations from the two columns, call `drop_duplicates()` on those columns:

```
unique_combs = data[['one', 'two']].drop_duplicates()

unique_combs
Out[32]: 
  one two
0   a   z
1   a   y
2   b   y
```

Comment: I don't know why that didn't click.  I even use that elsewhere in my code.  Kind of embarrassed to be honest but maybe this post will help somebody else sometime.

Comment: @Chris Whenever I want to do this I always try `.unique()` first, then remember it only exists for series, not dataframes. I only remember `drop_duplicates()` on the second attempt.

Comment: I do the same thing.  I end up trying np.unique(df).  Glad to hear other people make the same mistakes I do :)